# Massive Update with foreign key dependencies

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, migration

I have the following query:

```
update largeTable 
set largeTable_id ='NA';
```

I would like to know what are the best practices to perform that kind of updates if we talk about a 45m records table. Should I consider a cascade update? Or is this automatically done?

I have the below query as an example to perform the updates in separate batches to avoid tlog space issues :

```
DECLARE @i INT=1 

WHILE (@i <= 10) 
BEGIN
    UPDATE TOP(20000) largeTable 
    SET largeTable_id = 'NA'

    SET @i = @i + 1 
END
```

So, that's pretty much the idea, any comment or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :).

Adding a new idea:

```
--T-SQL using the ROWCOUNT setting to control update size
SET ROWCOUNT 1000 

WHILE (1 = 1) 
BEGIN 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 

    UPDATE tableB 
    SET TableB_TableA_id = 'NA'; 

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
    BEGIN 
        COMMIT TRANSACTION 
        BREAK 
    END 

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END 

SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

The main goal is to perform that update in multiple batches avoiding issues in the tlog datafile and perform the cascade updates with no performance issues.

Comment: I think you're missing an = in your example.

Comment: Doing this in batches is a great idea. However, you are updating the top 20000 rows but you don't specify an order so you are likely going to update the same 20,000 rows 10 times. I would suggest adding a where clause in there. And use a while @@ROWCOUNT > 0 instead a fixed number of iterations. And of course there is the missing equals sign in your SET

Comment: And it is always a good idea to avoid needless updates - so add "where isnull(largeTable_id, '') <> 'NA' " - just in case those values do exist.

Comment: Yup sorry for the missing =:

Comment: What is the foreign key in your example?

Comment: Hey Allerman, 

In the example the forigein key that at the same time is primary key in another table is largeTable_id.

Comment: I'm thinking about the below solution and I'm modifying the query to looks as per below:


`--T-SQL using the ROWCOUNT setting to control update size
 SET ROWCOUNT  1000
 
WHILE (1 = 1)
  BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    
    
 update tableB
 set TableB_TableA_id='NA';
 
 
    
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
      BEGIN
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
        
        BREAK
      END
    
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
  END
 
SET ROWCOUNT  0`

Comment: Also, be aware that if you update *more than 5000* rows in a single transaction, SQL Server will use **lock escalation** and ditch the row-level locks it normally uses, and instead, it will lock **the entire TABLE** with an exclusive lock. So for the period of the transaction (until it's committed - or rolled back), not even read operations are possible on your table

Comment: hi marc_s, 5k row or more than 5% of the table's rows?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @AffectedRows INT, @BatchSize INT;

SET @BatchSize = 5000;    
SET @AffectedRows = @BatchSize;

WHILE (@Rows = @BatchSize)
BEGIN
  UPDATE TOP (@BatchSize) tableB 
  SET   TableB_TableA_id='NA'
  WHERE TableB_TableA_id <> 'NA';

  SET @AffectedRows = @@ROWCOUNT;
END;
```

Comment: Hello Mihai, 

Why this part   FROM tableB B ?

Comment: It is another form of UPDATE statement. I made it even simpler. Please recheck...